# Repeating alarm in android at the last day of every month using android studio

Tags: java, android

can someone help me in revising this code so that this function can fire an alarm at the end day of every month. currently am able to get the current month but the application is not firing the alarm at the end day of the month. thanks

@Nikem, Please this is my kind request, if possible shed for me some more light on how i can check if the alarm time has already passed and how to set the next alarm by a sample code since am new to coding in android.
my code is here:

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

```
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

// Cancel alarms
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);

```
    /* Set the alarm to start at 12:30 AM at the last day of every month */
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    if (currentMonth == Calendar.JANUARY || currentMonth == Calendar.MARCH || currentMonth == Calendar.MAY || currentMonth == Calendar.JULY
            || currentMonth == Calendar.AUGUST || currentMonth == Calendar.OCTOBER || currentMonth == Calendar.DECEMBER) {

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), //+1000*60,
                1000 * 60 * 5, pendingIntent);
    }

    if (currentMonth == Calendar.APRIL || currentMonth == Calendar.JUNE || currentMonth == Calendar.SEPTEMBER
            || currentMonth == Calendar.NOVEMBER) {

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), //+ 1000*60,//changed from setrepeating to setInexactRepeating
                1000 * 60 * 5, pendingIntent);
    }

    if (currentMonth == Calendar.FEBRUARY) {//for feburary month)
        GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        if (cal.isLeapYear(2016)) {//for leap year feburary month
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 29);
            manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), //+1000*60  changed from setrepeating to setInexactRepeating
                    1000 * 60 * 5, pendingIntent);
        } else { //for non leap year feburary month

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 28);
            manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), //+1000*60, //changed from setrepeating to setInexactRepeating
                    1000 * 60 * 5, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your reponse and generous support.

Comment: You have it wrong. Do not set repeating event. Just set `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY,30)` or 31 depending on the month length. After alarm rings, set next month's. Always check if alarm time has already passed, and if yes, set the next one.

Comment: Thanks @Nikem... i will make the changes and get you back to you!